# Rails asset pipeline and jquery plugins. What am I missing?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

In a Rails 3.2 project I've got an application.js file that looks like:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.hoverIntent
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require my_custom_js
```

And in my layout we're simply referencing `<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>`

The code in `my_custom_js.js` actually uses the plugin from `jquery.hoverIntent.js`, but when I load the page I get a javascript error saying that there is no such `hoverIntent` function available on the object even though I can inspect the elements and see healthy references to the existing files.

The kicker here is that if I move those two references *out* of `application.js` it loads just fine. i.e.:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery.hoverIntent' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'my_custom_js' %>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you use 'jquery-rails' gem ? If you use 'jquery-rails' gem. do not require jquery in application.js

Comment: I am using jquery-rails, but according to their docs (https://github.com/indirect/jquery-rails) you're supposed to include require jquery and require jquery_ujs in application.js. If I remove those lines, I get '$' is not defined and 'jQuery' is not defined errors.

Comment: No, I meant you just need to require jquery_ujs at the beginning, don't need to require jquery

Comment: Hurm. Just leaving `//= require jquery_ujs` also results in `$` and `jQuery` not defined errors. You sure about this?

Answer (score 0):

in your `/layouts/application.html.erb`, add these snippets in your `head` section to load jquery.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery" %>
<%= javascript_incldue_tag 'jquery.hoverIntent' %>
<%= javascript_incldue_tag 'my_custom_js' %>
```

this will load jquery on all your pages.

If you need more info on why application.js doesn't work, read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization) to find out more.  My only idea is that your plugin is not named `jquery.hoverIntent` or your paths are wrong.

Comment: Right, and that works fine, but why won't the `application.js` version work? Shouldn't that be functionally equivalent?

Comment: The paths are loading fine. In development mode it's showing included files with the right content for the plugin and my javascript. It just seems to be screwing with the load order and I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

OK. I figured it out and I feel dumb. The asset pipeline was working as intended, but I had previously precompiled the assets and it was serving up a previously precompiled `application.js` which was reloading jQuery, but none of the plugins.